# pagination for facebook-graph-api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pagination

I am using the graph-api to fetch data for a specific query.

I am using the value of "**next**" field for pagination.
Suppose 
The link is http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=blade&type=post&limit=300&until=1322857230

This page has 2 links

"**previous**" and "**next**"

Now when i hit the previous link, i am getting results having latest time stamp.
How is this possible? Previous link should have data with older time stamps.

Answer (score 0):

That previous link has the updated data bcoz you are seeking the "blade" keyword until 2nd December so first page is getting the data from 2nd December and the previous one is getting the updated data , so on . But if you use http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=blade&type=post&limit=300&until=1323167000 then its searching until 6th December so there is no updated date for 6th December , thats why its previous page is blank .

Example :

Suppose there are 2000 post for "Blade" keyword from 2nd dec , So your query is returning the first 300 results starting from 2nd dec , lets say there are 500 results from 2nd December so in first page you are getting 300 and in previous page you will get rest of the 200 and another 100 result from 3rd December .

Make senses ?

Comment: so simply using the value from the "**next**" field is sufficient for pagination or to fetch maximum available results?

Comment: Actually it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: i want to have maximum data available for the specified query and for the specified date range. 
My base URL is http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=blade&type=post&since=2011-12-01&until=2011-12-03&limit=300&offset=0
from this i use the value in "**next**" fields for pagination.
So is this the right way to fetch all the data ? Or should i make use of the "**previous**" link too?

Comment: ok , what ever you use **since** or **until** the previous one is always the most updated result and next is the old result .

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding and guiding. I am now getting some insight on this.
will be back if i have more questions.

Comment: @raquibul-islam how could you say that **since** is the most updated result while [Api Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) says a different point.